# How many one-to-one functions are there that map from a set of cardinality 10 to cardinalities 7, 11, 15, 20

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This question is giving me a lot of trouble conceptually, I am pretty sure this is right, but I can't prove it to myself. Here is my attempt at an answer:

for cardinality $7$, no injective functions exist because the size of the codomain is  smaller than the domain, meaning that unless $f$ is a partial function, there must be some element in $A$ that maps to $2$ or more elements in $B$.

for cardinalities $11$, $15$, $20 = n$, I think it is $P(n, 10)$. Which would end up being $ n!\over(n-10)! $ right?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I screwed up the definition of the $P$ function :|

Comment: You are right! An other way of seeing it is the first element of $A$ has $n$ possibilities, the second $n-1$, ..., The tenth $n-10+1$. So $n\times(n-1)\times\dots\times(n-10+1)=P(n, 10)$

Comment: Yep thanks so much, I wasn't entirely sure but you clarified, thanks :)